# Online resource which tracks new words that are evolved or discussed

Tags: discussion, resources

My primary question is if there is any resource which keeps a track of words that evolve. Also before the word gets into any publication's dictionary "is there any process that is followed to evaluate if the "term under discussion" has enough credit to be qualified as a word and get into the dictionary.

Comment: Better on meta?

Comment: Possibly better on Meta. Questions about resources rather than the language itself aren't really on-topic here. The [OED's FAQ](http://public.oed.com/about/frequently-asked-questions/) may help with this, though.

Comment: Different dictionaries have different methods and different criteria. The Oxford English Dictionary invites help from members of the public: http://public.oed.com/appeals/

Comment: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/words-and-language/blog for one. There are more.

Comment: @BarrieEngland How about http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/press-releases/23-august-2012/

Comment: Erm... isn't [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/) where they breed new words these days?

Comment: @BarrieEngland  thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: @Kris thanks for guiding me to move it to meta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merriam-Webster had the [Open Dictionary](https://web.archive.org/web/*/merriam-webster.com/opendictionary06/*) for that:

> You know that word that really should be in the dictionary? Until it actually makes it in, here's where it goes. Welcome to our collection of user-submitted words.

For example, here's their entry for [*facebook* as a verb](https://web.archive.org/web/20120112122044/http://www3.merriam-webster.com/opendictionary06/newword_search.php?word=facebook).

Comment: I can't access it from Turkey. It seems like there's a geo-restriction.

Comment: @orhantorun I think they shut the Open Dictionary site down. The first link redirects to the MW homepage and the second leads to nowhere in any country. (Kinda tempted to just delete this but I'll try to salvage it.)

Comment: @orhantorun Please see my recent answer. Those linked pages may have replaced the Open Dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @MarcInManhattan

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Merriam-Webster Open Dictionary, which I can't access to, [Cambridge Dictionary Blog](https://dictionaryblog.cambridge.org/category/new-words/) constantly shares new words and there are also tiny surveys about whether these new words should be included in the dictionary or not.

Answer (score 1):

Merriam-Webster has a page that discusses how words get into its dictionary:

- [How a Word Gets Into the Dictionary

  Part One: The Process](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/how-does-a-word-get-into-the-dictionary)

In addition, it keeps a list of words that it is considering for inclusion:

- [Words We're Watching](https://www.merriam-webster.com/topics/words-were-watching)
- [Words We're Watching (see all)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-were-watching/see-all)